# Iterate through a list of case class and just output a single case class

Tags: scala, scala-collections

How can I iterate through a list of case class and just output a single case class, selecting the only the row that fits a criteria.

For example, for a list of case class abc, I want to capture the row that meets certain criteria.

```
case class abc(id: int, mod: Int, a: Int, b: Int)
case class output(id: int, mod: Int, calc: Int)

val a = List( abc(1, 101, 56, 47),
              abc(1, 201, 34, 23))

val out1: Option[Output] = Some(output(1, 101, 103))

val b = List( abc(1, 101, 56, 47)
              abc(1, 202, 47, 56))

val out2: Option[Output] = Some(output(1, 202, 103))
```

Comment: What have you tried? - Also, how do you want to model that _"nothing is returned"_? with a `null` ? _(which is considered a bad practice)_, with an `Option`? - PS: Let me recommend you to take a look to the [**scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) I am pretty sure you can come up with a simple solution if you check all the stdlib does for you; for example i can think of a solution involving just one method call over the list and then a simple `if`.

Comment: Returning Option[Output] is also possible

Comment: So you want o calculate the max and then `.find(yourformula == max)`.

Comment: Or, if you want to have only one passage, foldLeft where you save the current max and replace it if you find better.

Comment: How can I compare between different rows with a simple if

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok the `find` after the `max` is unnecessary. - Neel, I said one method call and then a simple `if`, so the `if` is not the one doing the comparison over multiple rows, is the method call ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you can do what you want o achieve with:

```
list.foldLeft(None: Option[output]) {
  case (Some(oldMax), a) =>
    val newMax = ... // calculate output
    Some(if (check if new output is bigger) newMax else oldMax)
  case (None, a)
    Some(calculate first max)
}
```

I won't implement the comparison and calculation of output to not spoil the fun completely.